# Can I stop USB devices from disconnecting when using KVM switch?

Tags: windows-7, usb, kvm-switch

I have a [KVM switch](http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=175_TK-209K&cat=105) hooked up to my Win7 box, and every time I switch away, it seems to disconnect the USB devices - keyboard and mouse.

Is there a setting somewhere to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this is KVM switch specific. Some KVM switches emulate virtual keyboard, mouse and monitor for each computer it is connected to whereas some just switch away the connection without further processing. As all of us can guess, the switching type is much cheaper...

Not too much we can do here I believe...

Comment: Yes, it is KVM specific.  I would look at different KVMs and use the vendor's return policy to cycle through them until I got what I needed.

Comment: +1 -- This is a feature of the KVM switch itself.  The only way to change it is by getting a different KVM.  USB is designed to handle the disconnects/reconnects anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem in practice.  At least, I've never seen it be a problem.  Just don't go plugging an external HD or a flash drive into your KVM and you'll be okay.  :-)

Comment: i think what's troubling @chris is that it takes some time for the keyboard/mouse to initialise themselves on switching and it decreases productivity

Comment: Actually, the security monkeys force the VPN to disconnect for some reason.

Comment: And there's one problem with this theory:  when I switch over to my linux machine, there's no delay - the mouse & keyboard work right away, which leads me to believe that Windows is doing something.

Comment: windows takes quite a bit of time reinitialising hardware when they are plugged in. I don't know why but it simply happens...

Comment: In case someone comes here in 2023 (happy new year !) this is a nonsense. A KVM Switch is a USB hub, it redirect all data to the target computer... Nothing virtual in it...

Comment: @CodeKiller happy new year indeed. but this is no nonsense. back then, and now still, we have USB KVM switches which emulate a keyboard at each host. and keystrokes are sent only when it is connected. this way, there is no disconnection of devices during switching to another host.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

1. `Device Manager` > `USB Root Hub` > `Properties` > `Power Management` (tab)
2. Uncheck `Allow computer to turn off this device to save power`.
3. You can apply this to other devices under `Device Manager` > `Universal Serial Bus Controllers`
4. You may need to restart computer for this to take effect.

For me, the effect was not immediate, but after 1 week or so, the switch speed has increased dramatically (2-4sec).

Sometimes, I still wait like 13sec, but after restart or unplug, everything works fast again.

Best regards!

Comment: "Fast"? The issue is with disconnecting devices oO! I am facing the very same issue currently. No idea, how to solve it. Probably higher current on the external power supply will do tho.